# Join two for loops, separated by a print statement into one

Tags: python, for-loop

In the following code, everything is working as expected.

It gets a 4 character long user input that ends with 0.

And simply adds stores in a dictonary the occurances of vowels and consonants.

```
input =""   #get input from user

while 4 < len(input) or 4 > len(input) or input[-1] != "0": #string has to be 4 char long and end in 0
    input = raw_input("insert code:")

occurrences = {"a":0,"e":0,"i":0,"o":0,"u":0,"consonants":0}    #store the vouel count



for x in input:
    if x in occurrences.keys():
        occurrences[x] += 1  #count cowels
    elif x != "0":
        occurrences["consonants"] += 1   #count consonants


for x in occurrences:
    if occurrences[x] > 0 and x != "consonants":
        print x + ",",

print "were inserted",


for x in occurrences:
    if occurrences[x] > 0 and x != "consonants":
        print str(occurrences[x]) + ",",

print "times respectively"



if occurrences["consonants"] == 1:
    print "there was %d consonant"%occurrences["consonants"]
else:
    print "there was %d consonants"%occurrences["consonants"]
```

For the input "aef0" the program will print:

> e, a, were inserted 1, 1, times
>   respectively there was 1 consonant

My questions is about this particular lines.

I know there must be a better way to do:

```
for x in ocurrances:
    if ocurrances[x] > 0 and x != "consonants":
        print x + ",",

print "were inserted",


for x in ocurrances:
    if ocurrances[x] > 0 and x != "consonants":
        print str(ocurrances[x]) + ",",

print "times respectively"
```

It just feels sloppy.

What I don't like about it is that I'm calling twice the same for loop and I feel this could be only one move in a much more elegant way, but I'm not finding the way to do so.

A pseudo code (or whatever) of what I'm trying to achieve would be the following.

```
loop the dictionary
print all key with values >= 1
print "were inserted" only once
print all the respective vales.
print "times respectively"
```

As I said I want the same output, but expressed in a more elegant way, I'm assuming the elegant would imply only one for loop but any other (more elegant) options are welcome!

I thought about doing something like [this](http://pastie.org/1785538), but it's obviously not working. (Don't worry about it, it's just plain wrong, but the approach shows what I was aiming for)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the syntax for python string concatenation, but that would be the only way to use a single loop and still generate the specified output.

Comment: @BenVoigt: ohh lets see, that sounds like a good idea! I'll try it out. Thanks

Comment: Combine the loops. ditch the "respectively" and make the output more readable:  
 a was inserted 1 time
 e was inserted 1 time
 there was 1 consonant (or is this a homework question?)

Comment: @Steven it is auto-homework(?) it is not for a real project so simplifying the problem doesn't make sense at all. Thank for the advice anyway!

Comment: Seems like consonants is a bad fit in the dictionary - why not just leave it out as a separate variable?

Comment: `input` is a builtin, you might want to use a different variable name to avoid confusion with the `input()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to write your code might be something like this:

```
print ", ".join(k for k, v in occurrences.items() if k != "consonants" and v > 0),
print "were inserted"
print ", ".join(str(v) for k, v in occurrences.items() if k != "consonants" and v > 0),
print "times respectively"
```

You can shorten this a bit more by factoring out the search:

```
a = [(k, str(v)) for k, v in occurrences.items() if k != "consonants" and v > 0]
print ", ".join(x[0] for x in a), "were inserted",
print ", ".join(x[1] for x in a), "times respectively"
```

Comment: @Greg thanks I'm checking it out!! (and changing the typo) >.<

Comment: @Greg. maybe it is nicer if you split the second answer to use 2 print statements

Comment: @Greg Thanks for your answer, it's a little over my head and so I'm figuring it out. I'll check back as soon as I get it, thanks again!

Comment: @gnibbler: good point, that makes it easier to read and shows the symmetry.

Comment: @Greg: But there still are two loops, this doesn't achieve what the question asked.

Comment: @BenVoigt: True but I did say I was open to more elegant solutions :) I just don't like the way I coded it and wanted to see if there could be any better options.

Comment: Thanks @Greg ! Sorry it took me so long to come and re read the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few more problems with elegance and other things that matter more. For a start your users would revolt against having to type a `0` that you don't do anything meaningful with. In fact you need to dedicate code to ignoring it! Keeping the count of consonants in the dict is rather inelegant. You don't check whether the user typed all letters. You don't handle uppercase.

Here's some code that addresses those issues plus a few verbosities:

```
input = ""   # get input from user
while len(input) != 3 or not input.isalpha():
    input = raw_input("insert code:").lower()
ocurrances = {"a":0, "e":0, "i":0, "o":0, "u":0}
nconsonants = 0
for x in input:
    if x in ocurrances:
        ocurrances[x] += 1  #count vowels
    else:
        nconsonants += 1   #count consonants
for x in ocurrances:
    if ocurrances[x]:
        print x + ",",
print "were inserted",
for x in ocurrances:
    if ocurrances[x]:
        print str(ocurrances[x]) + ",",
print "times respectively"
if nconsonants == 1:
    print "there was 1 consonant"
else:
    print "there were %d consonants" % nconsonants
```

and you might like to change "ocurrances" to "occurrences". By the way, if the number of vowels is less than 2, the output is not very pretty.

Comment: you can also use `ocurrances = dict.fromkeys('aeiou',0)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Some context, this was a very simple exercise we did in class and I got hanged up doing it trying out different things, trying to improve my familiarity with dictionaries, I actually started with consonants outside but got them in the dictionary to "complicate" the dictionary a bit more and learn how to handle it. The 0 is part of the stupid exercise, I agree it would be absolutely annoying.This will never implemented, I was just intrigued by this "identical" for loops so close to each other and though I could fit all in the first one. Thanks Again!!